# How can i get link elements with the feed framework (libs-for-android)

Tags: android

For a project we use the feed framework [libs-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/FeedFramework). The demo is very good but we can't find out how to grab the link elements in the feed. We try

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            Entries._ID, Entries.TITLE_PLAINTEXT, Entries.SUMMARY, Entries.CONTENT,
            Entries.ALTERNATE_HREF, Links.HREF
    };
```

but Links.HREF is null. Does anyone have a suggestion? The  [xml can you find](http://www.atomenabled.org/atom.xml) here (Atom feed)

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:* Does `Entries.ALTERNATE_HREF` contain the value you're looking for?

*Long answer:* The columns in the projection must all come from a single table (in this case, `Entries`).  Cursors are flat, so to access nested elements the caller must either perform a second query, or pack child elements into a string or blob column.  Another option is to define a column like `ALTERNATE_HREF`, which is basically just shorthand for the `href` attribute of the first `rel="alternate"` link element.  There are a couple more columns like this defined in `AtomContract`, including `Entries.ENCLOSURE_HREF` and `Entries.RELATED_HREF`, but you might need to write your own `AtomContract` and `AtomContentHandler` if the data you need is not exposed.

Comment: The values i need are the link elements in the entry elements. These values are stored in the LinkListener of the AtomContentHandler.
For <feed> elements there is a call

    Bundle extras = cursor.getExtras();
    String feed = extras.getString(Feeds.TITLE_PLAINTEXT);

Now i'am looking for same idea how i can grab the link elements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the "short answer". I write my own `AtomContract` and now the link is stored in `Entries.ALTERNATE_HREF`

Thanks libs-for-android!